# How to use system.drawing in a gtk# project

Tags: c#, mono, system.drawing, gtk#

I am aware that gtk# supports 2 drawing libraries, `system.drawing` (so compatible with windows or something) and `mono.cairo`. I want to ask

Firstly: Which is better to use in terms of capabilities?

Secondly: How do I use `system.drawing` in a gtk# project. I am aware that some sort of `ExposeEvent` is used but have no idea what it is and the concept behind it, please include this and any other theory/concepts that is required in your answer. Please also give an example of drawing a line across the form.

I am likely going to use system.drawing so please focus your answer on the second part of the question, especially the theory/concept part. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

*A few of my own ideas and might not be 100% correct.*

[GTK+ depends on Cairo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B). Mono.Cairo allows you to expose graphics from GTK+ widgets as Cairo objects, as demonstrated in [this article](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo). Such graphics are indeed Cairo objects. Note that GTK# cannot be used without Cairo.

GTK# is compatible with Windows and other operating systems, due to GTK+ the underlying framework's cross platform compatibility. It is not because of `System.Drawing`.

GTK+ does not depend on GDI+, and **GTK# does not depend on `System.Drawing` as well**.

GTK# does support `System.Drawing` in some aspect. For example, you can expose graphics from GTK+ widgets as `System.Drawing` objects, as demonstrated in [this article](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpNewInVersion2x) under Gtk.Dotnet section. GTK# converts the Cairo objects to equivalent `System.Drawing` counter parties.